# Why can't selenium click a React JS element? Doesn't raise error

Tags: python, selenium

I can't seem to get Selenium to click on this element properly. The website runs on React JS. The target element is in a div of `div`s (Is this just a react thing? Why not use a `ul`?) nested like so: `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]`.

Here is how my code is structured currently.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("my_class_name")

my_list = []
for row in rows:
   cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
   data = {"link": cells[0], "status": cells[1].text}
   my_list.append(data)

for item in my_list:
    if item["status"] == "new":
    item["link"].click() 
    Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/select"))
    select.select_by_value("my_value")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I have the program grabbing the full cell in the list object, as the cell is just another `div` with no `href` property. It does however have a `data-tag='allowRowEvents'` property, could I use this to click the element? In addition, the first object in the `div` of `div`s seems to function correctly and is able to click the element.

Comment: `on this element properly` Where it is? show the html structure of DOM element. Do not add the screenshot of it. No one will write html by looking into image for you.

Comment: Hey there. I'm not too sure what you're referring to. Could you elaborate? Thanks. @Dev

Comment: We don't know what is your exact problem try to add the maximum information to it in order to get the right and complete answer. Please read [mcve]. In your post how the html code of element looks like is not given and it makes difficult to understand starting of your post. So asked you to add it as code and not the screenshot so that people can debug it properly. If possible share the actual site URL.